# Backstage Techdocs does not render the documentation page. Stuck at "Step 3 of 3: Publishing docs for entity component..."

Tags: backstage

[image]

Techdocs page is stuck at `info: Step 3 of 3: Publishing docs for entity component:default/ssr-demo-1 {"timestamp":"2023-08-11T03:39:51.346Z"}`

I have built Backstage Docker image following the multi-stage build Dockerfile provided in the documentation: https://backstage.io/docs/deployment/docker#multi-stage-build

```yaml
techdocs:
  builder: 'local' # Alternatives - 'external'
  # generator:
  #   runIn: 'docker' # Alternatives - 'local'
  #   dockerImage: docker.io/pointmekin/kroki-server:0.0.1 # Docker image for the kroki server
  #   pullImage: true
  generator:
    runIn: 'local'
  publisher:
    type: 'local'
```

I noted that if I set the `runIn` to "docker", then this will break the production build since it will be using Docker inside Docker. Thus, I have used the multi-stage build Dockerfile to install the `mkdocs-techdocs-core` separately in the Dockerfile

```
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.1.7
...
```

This is the full Dockerfile.

```
# Stage 1 - Create yarn install skeleton layer
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS packages

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

COPY packages packages

# Comment this out if you don't have any internal plugins
# COPY plugins plugins

RUN find packages \! -name "package.json" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -exec rm -rf {} \+

# Stage 2 - Install dependencies and build packages
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS build

# Install isolate-vm dependencies, these are needed by the @backstage/plugin-scaffolder-backend.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 g++ build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3

# Install sqlite3 dependencies. You can skip this if you don't use sqlite3 in the image,
# in which case you should also move better-sqlite3 to "devDependencies" in package.json.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.1.7

USER node
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=packages --chown=node:node /app .

# Stop cypress from downloading it's massive binary.
ENV CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=0
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --network-timeout 600000

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN yarn tsc
RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend build
# If you have not yet migrated to package roles, use the following command instead:
# RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend backstage-cli backend:bundle --build-dependencies

RUN mkdir packages/backend/dist/skeleton packages/backend/dist/bundle \
    && tar xzf packages/backend/dist/skeleton.tar.gz -C packages/backend/dist/skeleton \
    && tar xzf packages/backend/dist/bundle.tar.gz -C packages/backend/dist/bundle

# Stage 3 - Build the actual backend image and install production dependencies
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim

# Install isolate-vm dependencies, these are needed by the @backstage/plugin-scaffolder-backend.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 g++ build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3

# Install sqlite3 dependencies. You can skip this if you don't use sqlite3 in the image,
# in which case you should also move better-sqlite3 to "devDependencies" in package.json.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.1.7

# From here on we use the least-privileged `node` user to run the backend.
USER node

# This should create the app dir as `node`.
# If it is instead created as `root` then the `tar` command below will fail: `can't create directory 'packages/': Permission denied`.
# If this occurs, then ensure BuildKit is enabled (`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`) so the app dir is correctly created as `node`.
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the install dependencies from the build stage and context
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /app/yarn.lock /app/package.json /app/packages/backend/dist/skeleton/ ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 600000

# Copy the built packages from the build stage
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /app/packages/backend/dist/bundle/ ./

# Copy any other files that we need at runtime
COPY --chown=node:node app-config.yaml ./

# This switches many Node.js dependencies to production mode.
ENV NODE_ENV production

CMD ["node", "packages/backend", "--config", "app-config.yaml"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation.

I fixed it by changing the publisher type to "awsS3" and then configuring the authorization to AWS S3. I think it should work well with other cloud providers too.

Read more about configuring cloud storage for TechDocs [here](https://backstage.io/docs/features/techdocs/using-cloud-storage/)